# Delete all Contents from postgreSQL

Tags: database, postgresql

i have a Database with a lots of Tables.

is there a way to clear the contents of the Tables without to do that for each Table! i mean a way to iterate the Database Tables List and delete its contents.

Thanx for your help.

Comment: How about pg_dump with the schema-only flag set? You don't say which version of Postgres so I will post the link for 9.1.  http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/app-pgdump.html

Comment: Any reason why you don't drop the whole database and recreate it?

Comment: @ojf i have version 9.3.9 running on Linux

Comment: @kliron when i drop the whole database i have to resinstall a lot of other tools. this is why i thought that clear the Tables Contents is the fastest way.

Comment: Do you want to _drop_ the tables, or just delete the data in the tables?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name just the data inthe tables

Comment: Ok, so can't you do the work in a bash script for example?

Comment: @kliron yes i can but how ?

Comment: Use the Truncate command in PostgreSQL. http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/sql-truncate.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A simple database function which iterates over all tables in a schema and clear his content. **WARNING: this function clear all tables without asking if you are sure :) Use with caution! No warranty!**

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION clear_tables_in_schema(_schemaname TEXT)RETURNS VOID AS
  $$
  DECLARE _tablename TEXT;
  BEGIN
    FOR _tablename IN SELECT tablename FROM pg_catalog.pg_tables WHERE schemaname = _schemaname LOOP
      RAISE INFO 'Clearing table %.%', _schemaname, _tablename ;
      EXECUTE format('TRUNCATE %I.%I CASCADE;', _schemaname, _tablename);
    END LOOP;
    IF NOT FOUND THEN
      RAISE WARNING 'Schema % does not exist', _schemaname;
    END IF;
  END;    
  $$
LANGUAGE plpgsql;
-- Usage:
SELECT clear_tables_in_schema('your_schema');
```

Comment: This will fail on any serious database due foreign keys - you can't truncate a table that is referenced by another table. You would need to truncate all tables at once.

Comment: Thanks, I added the clause `CASCADE`. @user3232446: I update my answer and modified the function.

Answer (score 0):

Something like:

```
#!/bin/bash

# Save the schema
pg_dump -U user --format plain  --schema-only --file db_schema.sql dbname    

com="psql -h host -U user -d dbname"

$com <<EOF
DROP TABLE foo;
DROP TABLE bar;
DROP TABLE baz;
# ... more tables here ... 
EOF

# Recreate all tables
$com < db_schema.sql
```

Comment: Of course the above assumes that the table names are constant and known beforehand. If not, use Tommaso's solution below or if you feel hackier grep the names from the db_schema file :-)